# Trying to find object in an array of objects that has a field of a certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models. Users, Votes, Photos. in a view I'm trying to see if the current logged in user has voted on the photo so I can display different html with different classes to show the user what they have voted on.

I have all the associations set up correctly. My issue is that I'm not sure how to determine if the user voted or not.

I have my code like so in my view `<%= photo.votes %>` Now since Photos can have many votes this grabs the array of all `vote` objects associated with that Photo. I want to loop through this array and check to see if the current signed in user's id is contained in any of the `vote` objects. I was hoping Rails had some sort of helper for this since I didn't want to just do a for loop through the array and check every object myself.

Is there a rails way for doing this (or just a better way in general, it seems slow) or is the best way really something like

```
photo.votes.each do |u|
  if u.userid == current_user.id
     do blah
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method:

```
photo.votes.select{ |u| u.userid == current_user.id }.each
  do blah
end
```

or if your idea is to just count the votes:

```
theCount = photo.votes.select{ |u| u.userid == current_user.id }.count
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I needed. Essentially a boolean telling me if they did or didn't vote and the count essentially works that way! I'm extremely new to rails so didn't know the select method existed.